# Source file is correct, actual print is moved to the right and bottom using system.drawing printing

Tags: c#, printing, scale, system.drawing

I've inherited an application created by people who are no longer working for my employer and I'm looking into a printing issue where the output (slightly) falls off the page.

It should be:

[image]

But it comes out like this:

[image]

*I've added the black borders for legibility on this page.*

So as you can see, the print is shifted slightly to the right and to the bottom, so that it surpasses the allowed boundaries.

**My question**

I'm going through the code, looking for options that may cause this, but I'm drawing a blank right now.

***Option A (ideal solution):***

> Any ideas on what may be causing this shift to the right-bottom?

***Option B***

> Any idea how I can shrink the scaling of what's being printed, so that
>   the content no longer falls off the page?

*Let me know if you need code to help clear out what's going on (I can't narrow things down enough up front to post any).*

Comment: Looks like a mechanical problem to me, the paper is not quite aligned correctly.   It bit too far to the left and in. In fact, the printout looks designed to show exactly such a problem.  Do ask somebody in the your company that's been around for a while what its intention was.  In which case there should be a documented procedure to adjust the paper feed mechanism.

Comment: I used the print out exactly to test how skewed the print is, because I noticed that the margins were off even though they are at 0. And it's not the printer itself, because if I print it directly it's fine, its only when I print via code that it's off.

Comment: If you downvote, please note why.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to solve this problem just by looking at those images? I think you should include your code, otherwise it's impossible to provide an answer...

Comment: at least tell us what control are you using. I have absolutely no clue what these white rectangles are.

Comment: @Bizhan: There is no control, they are samples of a printer test page, how it should print and how it's actually printed.

Comment: You see, you might have a clearer image in your mind about the situation because you've worked with it and seen at least a few related lines of code, but without no code I don't know where to begin. At least write **one** line that prints this test prints

Comment: I am not sure about this but Just a hack have you tried setting up margins in minus? I mean instead of setting the margin to 0 set to -1.

Comment: @Spikee does the answer solved your problem?

Comment: No solution yet ... thanks for the info though.

Comment: I just have this issue, however, I slightly print outside of the defined `PageSettings.PrintableArea`. Have you tried to read, and check and consider the values of the `PrintPageEventArgs.PageSettings.PrintableArea` property?

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't published your code, It's a bit harder to answer your question but here are 2 solutions to your problem:

on your System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class, 
override the default OnPrintPage and change the page margins:

```
protected override void OnPrintPage(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPrintPage(e);
    // Create a new instance of Margins with 1-inch margins.
    e.PageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100,100);
}
```

you can read more about the Margins property [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.margins?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

you can also play with the settings in the follow way:

```
        protected override void OnPrintPage(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Run base code
            base.OnPrintPage(e);

            //Declare local variables needed

            int printHeight;
            int printWidth;
            int leftMargin;
            int rightMargin;
            Int32 lines;
            Int32 chars;

            //Set print area size and margins
            {
                printHeight = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
                printWidth = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right;
                leftMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left;  //X
                rightMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top;  //Y
            }
        }
```

you should read that [following guide](https://andres.jaimes.net/71/printing-in-csharp-the-easy-way/) to learn and change it to fit your own needs